# How to stop being directed to admin.php after sending request to admin-ajax.php

Tags: ajax, forms

On my plugin admin page, I have make an ajax request to admin-ajax.php. For some reason, once the request is made, another request is made to admin.php which directs me away from my current page...

Here's my javascript:

```
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('POST', ajaxurl, true);
  request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

  request.onload = function() {
    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
      // Success!
      document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = '<p>' + request.responseText + '</p>';
    } else {
      document.getElementById('warnings').innerHTML = '<p>' + request.responseText + '</p>';
    }
  };
  request.send(serialise(data));
```

That request works fine, it hits my callback and the relevant data gets passed back to the page. However, I'm almost instantly making a separate request to admin.php automagically and it's directing me away from the current page.

[image: requests]

As you can see, the request to admin.php takes the parameters passed to the admin-ajax.php, excluding the action which suggests that the form I'm taking input from is being submitted, even though is has no submit button.

```
<form id="add-property-form">
  [all my inputs]
  <button onClick="addProperty()">Add property</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

As suspected, Wordpress was treating the button as `type="submit"` fixed by doing:

```
<button type="button" onClick="addProperty()">Add property</button>
```